# Spring HTTP cache management

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, browser-cache, cache-control

I've seen that you can control cache http headers with the AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter bean.

My problem is that I need to have a fine grane control on the cache (at method level).
The best think would be to have something like an annotation like "@RequestCache(expire=60)".

Is there anything like this?
What is the best way to accomplish this task?

Thanks,
Andrea

**Update:**
pap suggest to use an HandlerInterceptor, but I've seen multiple forum's post saying that it's not possible to get the target method inside an HandlerInterceptor and suggest to use regular AOP instead (not specifically for caching).
The problem is that I don't want to add the request parameter to all my methods, only to make it accessible to the aspect. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following approach described in 
[Spring mvc reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

> Support for the 'Last-Modified' Response Header To Facilitate Content Caching

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/modified")
@ResponseBody
public String getLastModified(WebRequest request) {
    if (request.checkNotModified(lastModified.getTime())) {
        logger.error("Was not modified.");
        return null;
    }
    logger.error("Was modified.");
    //processing
    return "viewName";
}
```

Comment: Does this work for returning images in combination with @ResponseBody as well?

Answer (score 2):

One way (that I have used myself) is to create your own [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html).

```
public class CacheInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        Class<?> o = AopUtils.getTargetClass(handler);
        if (o.isAnnotationPresent(RequestCache.class)) {
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", o.getAnnotation(RequestCache.class).expire());
        }
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

and then

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <array>
            <bean class="bla.bla.CacheInterceptor " />
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Good solutions but, if I understand, with AopUtils you can get the target class (the controller) but not the target method. Is there a way to check the annotation at the method level?

Comment: Not easily. I wanted to do the same thing, but it's not readily obtainable. I ended up annotating the entire class (and split controllers when needing different caching strategies).